# How to modify the li items with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

My HTML:

```
<div class="widgetcontent">
    <ul>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-526">
            <a href="a-test">A test</a>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-527">
            <a href="b-test">B test</a>
            <ul class='children'>
                <li class="cat-item cat-item-528">
                    <a href="test-b1">Test B1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="cat-item cat-item-529">
                    <a href="test-b2">Test B2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like:

If there is ul.children, modify with JavaScript and add the div.dropdown:

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-527">
    <a href="b-test">B test</a>
    <div class="dropdown" onclick="myFunction('cat-item-527')">▾</div><!-- ADD -->
    <ul class='children'>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-528">
            <a href="test-b1">Test B1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-529">
            <a href="test-b2">Test B2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

How to? Without jQuery or another JS framework. Native JS please.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Need onclick the added div.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by finding all `li` elements and then determining if there is a `ul` inside it. If so just add an element using [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

In this example I have coloured the element red just to indicate its added in the correct place.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("ul li.cat-item")].forEach(li => {
   const ul = li.querySelector("ul.children");
   if(ul){
     const div = document.createElement("div");
     div.classList.add("dropdown");     
     div.addEventListener("click",() => console.log("Clicked new div", li.className))
     li.insertBefore(div,ul)
   }
});
```

```css
.dropdown{
  height:10px;
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<div class="widgetcontent">
    <ul>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-526">
            <a href="a-test">A test</a>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-527">
            <a href="b-test">B test</a>
            <ul class='children'>
                <li class="cat-item cat-item-528">
                    <a href="test-b1">Test B1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="cat-item cat-item-529">
                    <a href="test-b2">Test B2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Jamiec, where do I paste JavaScript? In <head></head> or <body></body>? I'm sorry, but not working. The begin <script>document.querySelectorAll... is okay or how to begining? I do not know JavaScript.

Comment: @luckyluck31 it depends when you want this code to run. In response to a click? or when the page loads? or....?

Comment: I would like page load. How to and why not works for me? Please example how to for page load.

Comment: [...document.querySelectorAll - is it okay?

Comment: @luckyluck31 see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load?rq=1

Comment: I would like: <head><script>document.onload = function ... Is it work? How to?

Comment: @Jamiec How to write a console log cat-item-527? Not working: console.log("Clicked new div"+li.classname)

Comment: @jozs2021 javascript is case sensitive so it is `li.className`